# The Login cannot be display on the Microsoft edge

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js. I am not sure whether it is my code or my computer system causing this problem. The localhost:3000\login refuse to connect.
My code

```
const http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    body = [];
    
    req.on('error',(err)=>{
        console.log(error);
    }).on("data",(chunkdata)=>{
        body.push(chunkdata);
        console.log(chunkdata.toString());
    }).on("end",()=>{
        body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        if(req.method =="POST"){
            if(req.url=="/login"){
                console.log(body)
                var user = JSON.parse(body);
                const {username,password} = user;
                res.statusCode =200;
                res.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                res.write("Your usename is "+username +"and password is "+password );
                res.end();
            }
        }
    })

   
})
    

server.listen(3000,() => { 
  console.log("Server connected");
});
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

I try using Postman and it working fine

Answer (score 1):

If you directly trying to go `localhost:3000\login` on your browser that means you are making a GET request but you defined `/login` route as POST in your code.

Comment: I have send the data using Postman through the POST method but I could not get the response when I log in into the browser through Localhost:3000\login